# Fermat's Theorem as a primality tester doesn't work for all primes?

Tags: cryptography

I'm studying cryptography. According to Fermat's theorem... 
$$a^{p-1} \pmod p = 1$$ 
.. when $p$ is a prime number. The above should prove whether a number is prime or not yet it doesn't work for simple primes like $7$...

Having ran through a routine to show all values up to $50$ it seems to indicate that only $17$ passes the primality test as being probably (or in this case definitely) a prime. Had I picked random values for $a$, every other prime number from $1$ to $50$ would have failed the test.

**Result of prime modulus $7$**

$$8 = (2^{6}) \mod 7$$
$$8 = (3^{6}) \mod 7$$
$$8 = (4^{6}) \mod 7$$
$$8 = (5^{6}) \mod 7$$
$$1 = (6^6) \mod 7$$

**Result of prime modulus $17$**
$$1 = (2^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (3^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (4^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (5^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (6^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (7^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (8^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (9^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (10^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (11^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (12^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (13^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (14^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (15^{16}) \mod 17$$
$$1 = (16^{16}) \mod 17$$

Have I misunderstood the use of the theorem as a primality tester?

Comment: Note that $8=1 \mod{7}$ so it does work for $7$.

Comment: @MattB thanks, I understand now.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary but not sufficient to determine primality.  That is, you wrote "...when p is a prime number" which says the equation holds for prime p, but says nothing about non-prime p.  It turns out to not hold for many composites, which makes it a nice compositeness test.  If we run an arbitrary number $n$ through the test with some $a$, either it does not hold, in which case we are *certain* that $n$ is composite, or it does hold in which case all we know is that $n$ might be prime (but could very well not be).

As Amey pointed out, there is a class of composite $n$ values where the equation holds for all $a$ values: the [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).  Adding just a little more work yields the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) which doesn't have this issue.  However it still leaves one with the situation from the paragraph above where the results are "definitely composite" and "maybe prime".   Run the M-R test enough times with different $a$ values and we can bump that to "probably prime" (note the handwaving about what "enough" and "probably" mean).  There are also deterministic versions for "small" numbers, as well as the [BPSW probable prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test), and various proof methods.

Answer (score 2):

All prime numbers satisfy the equation. However, certain non-primes, called [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), also do. Therefore, we cannot use it to tell a prime from a composite number.